# Kubernetes failed to discover supported resources: getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am going through the kubernetes tutorial at Udacity. When i run the the nginx image using the following command

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx:1.10.0
```

It given me the error

> error: failed to discover supported resources: Get http://localhost:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused

If i try to get pods using the following command

```
kubectl get pods
```

it says

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

The nginx server is running, i can tell because i can get the appropriate output by running curl http://127.0.0.1

I am not able to figure out what the issue is, and there are not a lot of resources on the internet for this problem. Can anyone please tell me how do i resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your kubectl config file (`~/.kube/config`)

For testing purposes, you can use the admin one:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf get po
```

Or (again, for testing)

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

You can see more suggestions in [`kubernetes/kubernetes` issue 23726](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23726#issuecomment-292776436)

As commented below, that requires [kubernetes to be installed](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-quickly-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/), for the node to be able to join a cluster:

```
sudo kubeadm join --token TOKEN MASTER_IP:6443
```

Comment: Sorry noob question but where can i find `~/.kube/config`? It is not in my home folder. I do not have kubernetes installed i have cloned a git repository and it is in another folder. `/etc/kubernetes` does not have kubernetes installed. I am running kubernetes on google cloud server, on top of ubuntu.

Comment: @sid0972 That might be the issue then: installing kubernetes would be a start, or joining a cluster. (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/)

Comment: Yes installing solved the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

This issue often occurs when `kubectl` can not find the configuration credential for the intended cluster.

Check `$HOME/.kube/config` for cluster configuration. If configuration is empty or configuration is set for a wrong cluster, regenerate configuration by running,

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <CLUSTER_NAME> --zone <ZONE>
```

This will update the configuration credential in `$HOME/.kube/config`.

Now, everything should work as expected.

Reference: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/feedback/issues/537

Comment: i got this response: The kubernetes API may not be available ...  in my case once i use this dependency :  spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config  throws this exception : io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failed to start websocket ...  the cluster ip retrieves 401

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple, as @VonC suggested, i did not have kubernetes installed, i followed [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-quickly-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/) tutorial, and now i can proceed with my work.

Answer (score 1):

> failed to discover supported resources ......

`kubectl` command line tools connects with kube-apiserver at port 8443 for its operations.

To proble whether the apiserver is up, try `curl https://192.168.99.100:8443`

If it fails, it means kube-apiserver is not running. 
Most probably minikube would not be running.

So try:

1. > minikube status
   >
   > minikube start

OR

2. restart the VM

Comment: minikube start worked for me, I thought starting kubernetes from docker app will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it is simply because you need the `kubectl run` command as root (e.g. sudo it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the zone first:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-b
```

then add a cluster there :

```
gcloud container clusters create io
```

now you can run the commands .
Let me know if found a problem there :)